# how to create an entity from a table with Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I have a given table that I would like to insert into my db.
I know S2 can create a table from an entity, but is the opposite possible?  I mean, is it possible to create an entity from a given table?

Otherwise, I guess I'll just have to create an entity to correspond to my table structure.

Comment: AFAIK, you're only able to make a table from an entity, and not the other way around.

Comment: Well, depends on your project: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html and http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/tools.html#reverse-engineering

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:import AcmeBlogBundle annotation
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities AcmeBlogBundle
```

This is a example from official documentation.This code creates all entities from your db(if you had specified your db in config file).